# add exception on onbeforeunload pure javascript

Tags: javascript, exception

I have this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'You are leaving now.';
};
```

jquery for exception on `<a>` links.

```
$('a').click(function () { window.onbeforeunload = null; });
```

How can I do the jquery exception in pure javascript?

Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: That code using jQuery ***is*** "pure JavaScript." It uses a library, which doesn't make the language either more or less pure. You mean "using the DOM directly" or "not using a library."

Comment: There is no "exception" here. By "exception" do you mean "event"?

Comment: @meagar: I eventually concluded he meant exception to the onbeforeunload message. E.g., an exception to the rule that it shows the message. Not a great choice of term. :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out guys. Sorry about that. Please feel free to edit my post for proper use of terms. Furthermore, I thought $ function is jquery-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use either `getElementsByTagName` or `querySelectorAll` to get a list of the `a` elements, and hook the `click` event on them, using that function as your event handler.

Assuming IE9+:

```
function unhookBeforeUnload() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(anchor) {
    anchor.addEventListener("click", unhookBeforeUnload);
});
```

If you have to support IE8 (but not earlier), you have to add a shim for `forEach` or use a simple loop, and you have to handle the fact it doesn't have `addEventListener`. Normally I wouldn't handle the latter on a case-by-case basis, I'd have a function to hook up event handlers that took care of it. (E.g., like jQuery does.) But just for completeness:

```
function unhookBeforeUnload() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var n, anchor;
for (n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) {
    anchor = list[n];
    if (anchor.addEventListener) {
       anchor.addEventListener("click", unhookBeforeUnload);
    } else if (anchor.attachEvent) {
       anchor.attachEvent("onclick", unhookBeforeUnload);
    } else {
        anchor.onclick = unhookBeforeUnload;
    }
}
```

That will work on any browser you're likely to find, even IE6.